# Firefox re-allow `alerts`?

Tags: firefox

I visit a page which uses the javascript `alert` function for a particular functionality.  Each time this alert pops up, Firefox puts a conspicuous box to prevent the site from `alert`ing ever again.  Well, on one of the many `alert`s, I accidentally clicked this box.  Now the site is non-functional.  How do I re-enable `alert`s for that site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To re-allow alerts in the Firefox website:

- Enter the website
- Show website info:

  - If the menu is enabled, click *Tools > Page Info*
  - If the menu is disabled, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
- Click Permissions
- Next to the "Open pop-up windows" permission, uncheck "Use Default"
- Click Allow
- Restart Firefox (for me it didn't work without it).

Comment: I believe the restart in and of itself would allow `alert`s. The "Open pop-up windows" is unrelated and allows sites to use `window.open()`.